# C# 2.0 function to get Second Word from string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I need to write a function that will return me the part after the first word (first whitespace).

For example I have got below string in C# 2.0.

```
string str = "M000. New Delhi"
```

Now I want to write a function which return "New Delhi" if `str` is passed.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Why "New Delhi"? I think it's not a "word"?

Comment: "New Delhi" is two words. Do you want to return the second word (in this case "New") or remove the first? Does the first word always end with a dot? Is it always only exactly one word before that dot? Please update your question to be a bit more specific; you will get better answers in return.

Comment: Am I the only one wo made cow sounds while reading the sample string?

Comment: @VVS: Because of "New Delhi"? ;)

Comment: @Guffa: Because of "M000" or "Mooo", as I read it :-)

Comment: @VVS: Yes, that is obvious, I just tried to add another level to the joke. :)

Comment: Isn't it great how we have to 'guess' what the OP is asking for? The original question didn't mention 'after first whitespace', or even 'after the first word'. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7736232/revisions This question deserves downvoting.

Comment: I think this was not so worst question as you people has done downvoting!! I assume experts looks all the questions, but it seems there are lots of guys who still needs improvement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the part of the string after the first space:

```
string city = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

This will also give a result even if there happens to be no space in the string. The `IndexOf` method will return `-1` in that case, so the code will return the entire string. If you would want an empty string or an exception in that case, then you would get the index into a variable first so that you can check the value:

```
string city;
int index = str.IndexOf(' ');
if (index == -1) {
  throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find a space in the string.");
} else {
  city = str.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string WhichIsBestDelhi(String str)
{
  return "New Delhi";
}
```

This has the added benefit of returning "New Delhi" no matter what string is passed!

Comment: +1 This is good but the requirement was `return "New Delhi" when passed "M000. New Delhi"` - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736232/c-2-0-function-to-get-second-word-from-string/7736304#7736304

Comment: But it DOES return "New Delhi" when "M000. New Delhi" is passed. Or "M00. New Delhi", or "moo, new! delhi?".

Comment: Very true. The really interesting part about this question is what to do when the string is not "M000. New Delhi" - and your answer is nicely consistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
 string  s = str.Split(new char[]{'.'})[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write a function which return "New Delhi" if str is passed.

Here you go.

```
public string NewDehliFunction(string str)
{
    if (str == "M000. New Delhi")
        return "New Delhi";
    else
        return "?"; // what happens here???
}
```

But the big question is "What do you want it to do when it is passed something else?"

Comment: Guys I was looking the generic function not specially for New delhi string

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Take the first index of " "(whitespace) *(5 for your string)*
- Step 2: Increment the number you found in Step 1, by 1 *(6 for your case)*
- Step 3: Take the substring of the given string with start index of
  the number you found in Step 2 *(str.Substring(6) for your case)*

  ```
      private static string ReturnThePartOfAStringAfterTheFirstWordAndWhiteSpace(string str)
      {
          if(str.Contains(" "))
          {
                int indexOfFirstWhiteSpace = str.IndexOf(" ");
                string remainingStringAfterTheFirstWhiteSpace = str.Substring(indexOfFirstWhiteSpace + 1);
                return remainingStringAfterTheFirstWhiteSpace;
          }
          else 
                return str;
      }
  ```

You can use this method for any string to find the part after the first whitespace, which means the part after the first word.

Answer (score 0):

It's all very unclear. Simplest case:

```
var result = str.Substring(6);
```

More sophisticated:

```
var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(". ")); // Possible off-by-one; can never remember
```

Comment: That's actually off-by-two... The result will be `". New Delhi"`.

Answer (score -1):

// replace the "M000. "

```
str.Replace("M000. ",String.Empty);
```